# How to get texts within the <b> tag in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I searched many preg_match expression but couldn't figure this out. I want to fetch texts within the `<b>` tag from the following.

```
$string='<b>Joondanna
Investments Pty Ltd v The Minister for Lands, Planning and the Environment </b>(NTSC)
- discovery - judicial review - documents not relevant to question in
proceedings - application dismissed (C G)<br>';

preg_match( '/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/', $string, $match );           
echo $match[1]; //Undefined offset error
```

Comment: The entire matched string, including the html tags will be in 0, just the text, captured by `(.*?)` will be in 1.

Comment: why not just use an HTML parser for this

Comment: @Ghost, i need to insert the result into database...

Comment: @Nephil i was referring to HTML parsers which extracts those texts inside the markup. after getting that text, then continue on what you need to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the 's' pattern modifier so the dot will match everything, including newlines

change

```
preg_match( '/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/', $string, $match );
```

to

```
preg_match( '/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/s', $string, $match );
```

[more on pattern modifiers from the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)